# 36V inductive charging coil or multiple coils

Tags: inductive

I want to charge a 36V lithium battery using an inductive charging setup, input 36V and output 36V. Currently I am charging at 2 amps, so along those lines. I can only find coils online that work up to 12V. I have seen a product that can output 36V, but I cant find the components to build it.

Would wiring 3 x 12V in series work, or would the charging fields cause problems?

All ideas welcome.

Comment: "2 amps per hour" is not a correct measurement. You mean "I am charging at 2 amps". (The ampere is the rate of flow of charge so it already has the "per unit time" built in.) If you charge at 2 A for 3 h then you will have put 6 Ah of charge into the battery.

Comment: You will need 3 sets of coils placed far enough apart to avoid interference. Can you handle that?  Please provide a link to the coils you want to use.

Comment: Why can't you make your own coil? You're attempting to design your own wireless charging protocol, getting a loop of wire is the easy bit in that process.